# Supersede Existing operator<<: Override Existing Implementation

Tags: c++

A function like this exists:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const boost::dynamic_bitset<> &v) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    out << int(v[i]);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Wish to override it and use something like this. :)

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const boost::dynamic_bitset<> &v) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    if (i && v[i]) {
      out << ", " << i;
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Obviously C++ is not going to allow this. How do you overcome this and use an alternative logging functionality?

Comment: I've changed the title to "supercede" due to the specific meaning of "override" in C++.

Comment: @AmiTavory How about `Supersede an XYZ operator; Override a current existing definition?`. I like the use of correct terminology so imho supersede is better than the alternative (overloaded meaning of override).

Comment: @zehelvion There we go :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As opposed to @Bathseba's (correct) answer, I would avoid inheriting from the class: it is never really trivial as you might need several ctors, you might want wish to redirect differently in different settings, there might be other operations which you wish to specialize (like the redirection here), and so forth.

Instead, I would create a class just for redirection:

```
struct my_redirector
{
    my_redirector(const whatever &w) : m_w(w) {}
    const whatever &m_w;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &&os, const my_redirector &r)
{
     // whatever you want
     return os;
}
```

which you would use as:

```
whatever w;

cout << my_redirector(w) << endl;
```

The code is short enough in order to see, at a glance, why you created this class.

Comment: That's a good point about the constructors. Although later c++ standards obviate that.

Comment: @Bathsheba So is this a worthy answer iyho? It appears to be conclusive and brief to me which is a good quality for answers to questions that appeal to beginners and intermediate programmers which represent most of the population of users who may look for an answer on such a subjectively trivial question?

Comment: Thanks, @Bathsheba - you're right, of course. BTW, I've been very impressed with answers you wrote over a long time.

Comment: Yes, I like it a lot. (I was I think the second upvoter.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and taking the time to present a concise solution that works out of the box. It helped a lot in allowing me to get the desired log for my debugging needs. It allowed me to get more work done by avoiding messy temporary code used only for debugging purpose.

Comment: @zehelvion Thanks for the note - I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Inherit trivially from the boost class, ensure that v is of that type, and define the relevant operator.

C++ doesn't allow you to undefine a function, unfortunately.